# What's the role of Ground Plane in high frequency boards?

Tags: pcb-design, high-frequency

Here is an image of an [LNB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-noise_block_downconverter) circuit:

[image]

As you can see there is some Vias that is pointless for me(blue circles). Why didn't the designer connect these components to the ground line around the circuit directly?

Some of these Vias are connected to the ground line around the circuit and some are not connected. Does the Ground plane have a specific role in high-frequency PCBs?

Comment: This looks like an RF board. RF design is pretty specialized. All I can tell you is that the stitched conductor around the outside is for shielding. And as such they probably don't want to deliberately have current flow on it. Maybe those "useless" vias aren't even GND vias? Maybe they have to be that way to have the correct impedance at high frequency? Of all the fantastical things you see on this board, I am surprised that the vias are what you ask about.

Comment: If electronics is an art, RF is magic. There's a good writeup on Wikipedia, but I'll leave it to a magician that really understands this kind of thing to answer your specific question. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_element_filter

Comment: @mkeith: "pretty specialized" is an understatement from where I stand looking at that layout. Pretty weird constructs with those cone-copper areas below the blue circle.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, why is that via indicated by red-arrow on the layout, at the top left?

Because that via is grounding one side of a bypass capacitor; we don't know the level of current coming through that capacitor, but the human designer did not want that current to flow on the edge of the layout, where "slit antennas" are a bad idea and will radiate. Radiation inside boxes will cause coupling of circuits located far apart, and upset the gain flatness, the phase consistency, and possibly produce oscillation.

View every via as 1 nanoHenry of inductance. At 10GHz, that is j63 ohms of impedance. Wider holes give a lower impedance. In this example of yours, **NOTHING** can be absolutely clean or quiet, because of all the bits of metal.

As I was taught in past decades, "ground is just a cruel joke".

On the top right, the reasons are the same. Particularly those large black blobs with 4 thick pins out the 4 sides.

Don't view RF as magic. Just continue to expand your awareness of all the pieces of metal, all the vias, all the opportunities for coupling. Sometimes even the dielectrics are used for signal paths.